# Can anyone identify what this font is? Or a similar font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

The following is a screenshot of the dating application "Coffee meets bagel".

I was wondering if anyone can identify what the font being used is, or at least a similar font.

(I have already tried the guide, and I failed due to my own lack of artistic intuition)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using an android device. Typically apps use standard device fonts. So it should be a form of [Roboto by google](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Segoe UI is quite the same in Windows PCs. Se an example:

[image]

At least pair nj is rendered differently in your phone and Windows.

Comment: Look at the a and the s. And the j. And the g. They are not nearly the same.